# To Compare 2 dataframes

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to compare 2 data frames and obtain the mismatch row values using pyspark. Given df1 and df2 in the following format

```
df1 :
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
|   id|firstname|middlename|lastname|gender|salary|
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
|42114|   Robert|          |Williams|     M|  5000|    
|40288|  Michael|      Rose|        |     M|  4000|   
|39192|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|     F|  4000|
|36636|    James|          |   Smith|     M|  3000|       
|     |      Jen|      Mary|  Browln|     F|    -1|  
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
```

```
df2:
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
|   id|firstname|middlename|lastname|gender|salary|
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
|42114|   Robert|          |Williams|     M|  6000|    
|40288|  Michael|      Rose|        |     M|  4000|   
|39192|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|     M|  4000|
|36636|    James|          |   Smith|     M|  3000|       
|     |      Jen|      Mary|  Browln|     F|    -1|  
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
```

When there is a mismatch For eg the 1st-row salary column is mismatched. So both the values from df1 and df2 needs to be written side by side

```
Output

+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------++-----+---------+----------+--------+-
|   id|firstname|middlename|lastname|gender|salary|df1_gender|df2_gender|df1_salary|df2_salay
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
|42114|   Robert|          |Williams|     M |        |    |   |         | 6000.    | 50000
|
|39192|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|       |  4000   |  F  |  M  |      |          |
+-----+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
```

```py
conditions_ = [when(df1[c] != df2[c], lit(c)).otherwise("") for c in df1.columns if c != 'id']
select_expr = [
    col("id"),
    [df2[c] for c in df2.columns if c != 'id'],
    array_remove(array(*conditions_), "").alias("column_names")
]
df1.join(df2, "id").select(*select_expr).show()
```

I am getting like this. Can someone please help me with this

Comment: Since the mismatch is unpredictable, it's possible that all columns could be different (except ID I suppose), so we'd ended up with all columns are duplicated, am I understand correctly?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep the rows for which the is at least one mismatch. I would do it like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import functools

# a function that prefixes all columns but 'id' with the dataframe name
def rename_columns(df, name):
    renamed_cols = [col(c).alias(name + "_" + c) for c in df.columns if c != "id"]
    return df.select(["id"] + renamed_cols)

df1_join = rename_columns(df1, "df1").na.fill("")
df2_join = rename_columns(df2, "df2").na.fill("")

# a list of mismatch conditions
condition_list = [col("df2_" + c) != col("df1_" + c) for c in df2.columns if c != "id"]
# merging the list above into one condition
condition = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, condition_list)

result = df1_join.join(df2_join, ['id']).where(condition)
result.show()
```

```
+-----+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+
|   id|df1_firstname|df1_middlename|df1_lastname|df1_gender|df1_salary|df2_firstname|df2_middlename|df2_lastname|df2_gender|df2_salary|
+-----+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+
|42114|       Robert|          null|    Williams|         M|      5000|       Robert|          null|    Williams|         M|      6000|
|39192|        Maria|          Anne|       Jones|         F|      4000|        Maria|          Anne|       Jones|         M|      4000|
+-----+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

If it's important for you that the columns are displayed "side by side", you can re shape the dataframe like this:

```py
columns = [["df1_"+c, "df2_"+c]  for c in df1.columns if c != 'id']
ordered_columns = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, columns)
result = result.select(['id'] + ordered_columns)
```